# invalid qualifier error accessing ListBox properties

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here lstName is a name of a list box in Access form.

```
Private Sub cmdUp(lstName As String, SQLName As String, IDName As String, ColumnName As String)
  Dim sText As String
  Dim pText As String
  'check: only proceed if there is a selected item
  If lstName.ItemsSelected.Count = 1 Then
  (...)
```

After calling a procedure:

```
Call cmdUp(lstSchemaName.Name, "eo_ListSchema", "SchemaID", "SchemaName")
```

I get error it this line:

```
If lstName.ItemsSelected.Count = 1 Then
```

Error is:

```
Invalid Qualifier
```

So basically VBA cannot understant that lstName. is a list from which it should find how many items are selected.
I found that in VBA "strings are not objects, so there are no methods on the string variable that you can call".

There should be a simple solution, but I cannot find it. How to deal with this kind of problem?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Edgaras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstName` as you've passed it in will just be the string name of your listbox, not the actual listbox instance.

As this `lstName` is a string, calling `lstName.ItemsSelected` isn't valid.

You should be able to pass the listbox in instead:

```
Private Sub cmdUp(lstBox As ListBox, SQLName As String, IDName As String, ColumnName As String)
...
```

Then call this using:

```
Call cmdUp(lstSchemaName, "eo_ListSchema", "SchemaID", "SchemaName")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the listbox as a listbox, a string will not have any properties, or you could pass the string and a form object, which might be safer.

```
Call cmdUp(Me, lstSchemaName.Name, "eo_ListSchema", "SchemaID", "SchemaName")

Private Sub cmdUp(frm as Form, lstName As String, _
     SQLName As String, IDName As String, ColumnName As String)

   Frm(lstName) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need either pass ListBox as Lsitbox inside cmdUp procedure

```
Private Sub cmdUp(lstName As ListBox, SQLName As String, IDName As String, ColumnName As String)
```

or find appropriate control using its name like:

```
Dim myListBox As ListBox = Me.FindControl(lstName)
if myListBox.ItemSelected.Count = 1 Then
...
```